# Phoenix route with multiple ids

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I got something like

```
scope "/parent" do
  get "/", ParentController, :index
  get "/:id", ParentController, :show
  patch "/:id", ParentController, :update
  delete "/:id", ParentController, :remove
end
```

My parent got children and I want to add a route to remove the children, like

```
delete "/:id/:child_id", ParentController, :remove_child
```

My controller sigrature for the normal delete is

```
def remove(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
```

So

```
def remove_child(conn, %{"id" => id, "child_id"}) do
```

should work i guess.

But what about testing?
The normal delete looks this way:

```
conn = delete conn, parent_path(conn, :remove, parent)
```

How to pass the id of the child in the test?

```
conn = delete conn, parent_path(conn, :remove_child, parent, child)??
```

Comment: Does that not work? Try `child.id` instead of `child`?

Comment: Did not try it. https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html has no example for one route with multiple ids. Hoped someone here could help, because google did not work. I said "guess", because I don't know if it even works. Works in ASP.MVC, so i guess should work in phoenix also.

Comment: Thanks, worked. Controller with `%{"id" => id, "child_id" => child_id}` and in test `child.id` as parameter made it :)

Comment: could you add a answer and mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with code above. The named parameter made it.